# Angular2 reactive form error displaying

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to learn about Angular2's reactive forms by making a contact form. It all works good but there's an error that seems to give me quite some trouble. Everything works just fine when I use `Validators.required` but as soon as I add `Validators.minLength` or anything else on one of the controls everything messes up and I get this error in the browser's console: `Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.`. I looked around but I couldn't really find a simple explanation/ Here's my component:

```
export class ContactRouteComponent {
contactForm: FormGroup;
reasons = REASONS;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', <any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)],
        email: ['', <any>Validators.required],
        reason: ['',<any>Validators.required],
        message: ['', <any>Validators.required]
    });

    // AFISEAZA MESAJE EROARE
    this.contactForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
    this.onValueChanged();
}

onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.prepareContactForm());
    this.contactForm.reset();
}

prepareContactForm() {
    const formModel = this.contactForm.value;

    const contactValues: Contact = {
        name: formModel.name as string,
        email: formModel.email as string,
        reason: formModel.reason as string,
        message: formModel.message as string
    };

    return contactValues;
}

onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if(!this.contactForm) { return; }
    const form = this.contactForm;

    for(const field in this.formErrors) {
        // clear previous messages
        this.formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);

        if(control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
            const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
            for(const key in control.errors) {
                this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}

formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    'email': '',
    'reason': '',
    'message': ''
}

validationMessages = {
    'name': {
        'required': 'Name is required',
        'minLength': 'Name has to be...'
    },
    'email': {
        'required': 'Name is required'
    },
    'reason': {
        'required': 'Name is required'
    },
    'message': {
        'required': 'Name is required'
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 33):

When you have multiple validation rules, you must insert them inside of an array as such:

```
this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)] ]
    })
```

**Update to Angular v5**

A more recent implementation without `FormBuilder`:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', 
    Validators.compose([ Validators.minLength(5), Validators.email ])),
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When you add more than one validator in the form builder, you should use an array `[]` braces for the validators

```
this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', 
       [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
    ],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    reason: ['', Validators.required],
    message: ['', Validators.required]
});
```